# How can I configure the rotation orientation of Oculus Touch controls in A-Frame 1.4.0?

Tags: aframe

The forward direction of the Oculus controller since migrating to 1.4.0 has changed. This is noticeable in the direction of the teleportation-controls ray (dark blue line) compared to the laser-controls ray (light blue line). The child elements of the oculus controller are also affected by this as the position of the children objects are undesirable and match the teleportation-controls ray which is above the controller rather than sitting directly in front of the controller. Please create a way to configure the rotation orientation of the oculus controls or provide a fix.

To reiterate, both the laser-controls and teleportation line should be aligned. The previous orientation worked with our project whereas the current orientation breaks it. This is why it needs to be changed.

A screenshot is attached to provide context, thanks!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI66m.jpg)

- A-Frame Version: 1.4.0
- Platform / Device: Oculus Quest 2
- Reproducible Code Snippet or URL:

  ` <!---------------------------
  |      [ PLAYER RIG ]       |
  ---------------------------->

  ```
  <a-entity
    id="player"
    rotation="0 145 0"
    position="8.012 0 -6.058"
    simple-navmesh-constraint="navmesh:.navmain;fall:0.5;height:0;exclude:.exclude-main;"
    movement-handler
    movement-controls="speed:0.15;camera:#camera;enabled:true;"
    scene-boundary
  >
    <a-entity
      id="camera"
      position="0 1 0"
      camera
      look-controls="pointerLockEnabled:true;"
    >
      <a-entity
        carry-position-handler
        look-at="[camera]"
        id="carry-position"
        position="0 0 -1.3"
      ></a-entity>
      <a-entity
        id="cursor"
        position="0 0 -0.1"
        geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.001; radiusOuter: 0.002"
        material="color: black; shader: flat"
        cursor-handler
        cursor
        raycaster="objects:.interactable,.collidable;"
      ></a-entity>
      <a-box
        id="fade-box"
        scale="0.3 0.2 0.010001"
        color="black"
        shader="flat"
        side="double"
        visible="false"
      ></a-box>
    </a-entity>
    <a-entity
      id="right-hand"
      oculus-touch-controls="hand:right;"
      sound="src:url(media/oga/teleport.oga);on:teleported;"
      blink-controls="collisionEntities:.nav;landingMaxAngle:360;rotateOnTeleport:false;"
      laser-controls
      raycaster="objects:.interactable,.collidable;lineOpacity:1;lineColor:lightblue;"
      carry-controls
    >
      <a-plane
        id="info-hand-tablet"
        position="-0.05 0.1 -0.1"
        rotation="-50 10 0"
        scale="0.4 0.2 0"
        color="#222222"
        shader="flat"
        visible="false"
      >
        <a-text
          id="info-hand-text"
          position="0 0.01 2"
          scale="0.2 0.34 1"
          text="value:test"
          align="center"
          wrap-count="34"
        ></a-text>
      </a-plane>
    </a-entity>
  </a-entity>`
  ```